# Does Nuxtjs3 support NuxtServerInit

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3, pinia

I used Pinia for creating a data in Nuxtjs 3. It works correctly, But I'd like to check that the data is rendered through the server not just client.
How can I be sure about that? and Does nuxtServerInit is supported in new version of Nuxtjs 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try us this within creating plugin

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  if (process.server) {
    // ...
  }
})
```

Found exact answer related to Pinia:
**https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/947#discussioncomment-1943854**

Main source: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/bridge/bridge-composition-api#definenuxtplugin

EDIT: omit the import as Nuxt handle it

Comment: I think it can be improved by omitting the import (Nuxt 3 does this automatically) and removing the ```if (process.server)``` by naming the file like this: ```{plugin-name}.server.js```. Whit this name the plugin will execute only on server side

Comment: Yes, You're right, they have changed it into auto-import also inside plugins etc, thanks for pointing, going to edit post